# Which Messenger is more secured between AIM and Gtalk as we need this for interacting between the clients and End users

Tags: aim

We would like to know which Messenger is more secured for intercating with the cients between AIM and GTalk.Kindly require your valuable feedb

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be AIM or GTalk?  Have you considered looking at an open source xmpp/jabber client such as OpenFire with Spark?

If you go the AIM/GTalk route, you'll depend on them to keep the service up and running.

Answer (score 0):

One consideration is SSL/TLS support, which means messaging is encrypted, so it's much harder for somebody to eavesdrop on conversations.

Both support AIM and GTalk support SSL.

However, it sounds like GTalk doesn't support SSL using the official client, instead you would have to use something like [Pidgin](http://pidgin.im/).

You should probably also check whether AIM uses SSL out-of-the-box, because it will obviously be harder if you have to talk every user thru the process of turning SSL on.

If it's important that SSL be on by default, you might also want to consider MSN Messenger.

References:

- [Using AOL and AIM mail](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Using_AOL_Mail_with_Mozilla)
- [Enable SSL connections](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=100181)